# SET was unexpected at this time error message

Tags: solr

I am using solr-5.1.0. When I run the command
bin\solr.cmd it says that
SET was unexpected at this time.

```
C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>IF "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT"
setlocal nabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>REM Determine top-level Solr directory

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>set SDIR=C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-
.1.0\bin\

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>IF "\" == "\" set SDIR=C:\Users\Abhi\Desk
op\solr\solr-5.1.0\bin

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>set SOLR_TIP=C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\s
lr-5.1.0\bin\..

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>pushd C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1
0\bin\..

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>set SOLR_TIP=C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\s
lr-5.1.0

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>popd

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>REM Used to report errors before exiting
he script

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>set SCRIPT_ERROR=

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>set NO_USER_PROMPT=0

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>REM Allow user to import vars from an inc
ude file

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>REM vars set in the include file can be o
erridden with

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>REM command line args

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>IF "" == "" set "SOLR_INCLUDE=C:\Users\Ab
i\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0\bin\solr.in.cmd"

C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0>IF EXIST "C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr
5.1.0\bin\solr.in.cmd" CALL "C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr-5.1.0\bin\solr.in.md"
SET was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: It looks like the error is originating in `C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\solr\solr
5.1.0\bin\solr.in.cmd` can you post that?

Comment: @GregHNZ actually i didn't change any file it is same as orginal file that i downloaded from website this is the link of file:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85mKQ6Z8btzVi1ZRU5VQnQ5dnc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding

```
set SOLR_JAVA_HOME=<PATH\TO\YOUR\JAVA\DIR>
```

to my *"solr.in.cmd"* file.

Answer (score 2):

The following change to my solr.in.cmd file did the job:

```
set SOLR_JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set JRE path in

```
/bin/solr.in.cmd
```

Add below line to the file:

```
set SOLR_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66 // (JRE folder location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `CMD` and enter the following code:

```
set SOLR_HOME=C:\Users\Saad Tufail\Downloads\Compressed\solr-7.4.0\solr-7.4.0
set PATH=$PATH:$SOLR_HOME\bin
```